# cannot load image in isolated storage when creating IconicTile

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create IconicTile using image saved on isolated storage.

At first, I saved image to isolated storage.

```
// bitmap is Stream of image source (e.g. from PhotoChooserTask)
var wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
var file = "Shared/ShellContent/IconicTile.png";
// when file exists, delete it
if (storage.FileExists(file))
{
    storage.DeleteFile(file);
}
using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(file, FileMode.Create, storage))
{
    // use ToolStackPNGWriterExtensions
    wbmp.WritePNG(isoFileStream);
}
```

And I have confirmed PNG file is successfully created using Isostorage Explorer Tools.
Then I try to create IconicTile.

```
var initialData = new IconicTileData
{
    BackgroundColor = SelectedColor,
    IconImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/IconicTile.png", UriKind.Absolute),             
    Title = tbTitle.Text,
    WideContent1 = tbWideContent1.Text,
    WideContent2 = tbWideContent2.Text,
    WideContent3 = tbWideContent3.Text
};
var uri = string.Format("/SecondaryPage.xaml");

var TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(uri));
if (TileToFind == null)
    ShellTile.Create(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative), initialData, true);
else
    TileToFind.Update(initialData);
```

But image in the created tile are white.
(I'd like to attach image but my  reputation is too low. Sorry.)

I tried not only PNG format but also JPG format, but neither doesn't work.

Is there anyway to create IconicTile using image on IsolatedStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iconic tile format expects a transparent background, based on your comment at the first line (PhotoChooserTask), I suspect you're using some type of image with no transparency.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I confirmed image can be loaded successfully using transparent PNG saved at isolated storage. And I found another one condition, I must set BackgroundColor property of IconitTileData to Colors.Transparent.